# MySQL select query from two tables

Tags: mysql

I have two tables: **users** and **works**

I need write *select query* for **count different names from users table where work_status = 1 from works table**

[image]

**The total is**: 3 John, 1 Tom

I need get result:
    John 2 (*2 because one John work_status = 0 ant this not counting*)
    Tom 1

I have write select that can count different names, just need compared work_status..

```
SELECT name,COUNT(*) as num FROM users GROUP BY name
```

My query return:

[image]

Comment: This example Is totally wrong. Every user has only 1 work according to that relationship. Notice the `user_id` values in works table

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky  You're right. I rewrote my answer. I think There are three differnt John working on the company.

Comment: This is just data example, me real table not this (but i need that query)

Comment: But your example isn't correct, our answer could be incorrect too. They are three different John, or all of them are the same person?

Comment: @JCalcines, The example data is clear, albeit poorly chosen. I believe you are getting hung up on concept. If you imagine the names as categories, say gender (John=Male, Tom=Female); the query can then be seen as get me the count of works with status 1 for each gender.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple JOIN query:

```
  SELECT u.name, COUNT(*) num
    FROM users u
    JOIN works w
      ON w.user_id = u.id
     AND w.work_status = 1
GROUP BY u.name
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a problem in your question. So here you have two solutions.

If there are three different John working on the company, this is your query

```
SELECT u.name, COUNT(*) as num 
FROM users u INNER JOIN works w ON w.user_id = u.id 
WHERE w.work_status = 1
GROUP BY u.name, u.id
```

If there are only one John  working in the company, your query is this one:

```
SELECT u.name, COUNT(*) as num 
FROM users u INNER JOIN works w ON w.user_id = u.id 
WHERE w.work_status = 1
GROUP BY u.name
```

*Note: If three John are the same person, you should delete the 2 last and on the `works` table change `user_id = 3` and `user_id = 4` for `user_id = 1`*

Answer (score 1):

This one should do the job:

```
SELECT users.name,SUM(works.work_status) as num 
  FROM users,works 
  WHERE users.id=works.id 
  GROUP BY name
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
  users.`name`,
  COUNT(*) num 
FROM
  users,
  works 
WHERE users.`id` = works.`user_id` 
  AND works.`work_status` = 1 
GROUP BY users.`name` ;
```